# Get the Facebook fan pages the user owns/administrates

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook JavaScript SDK to get the all the fan pages that the logged in user owns/administrates.

```
FB.api('/me/accounts', function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

but this shows only the Facebook apps that I own. Am I using the wrong link?

**Edit**

I added this to my login button :

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_birthday,manage_pages" id="auth-loginlink"></fb:login-button>
```

and in the Auth Dialog (in the dashboard) i added `manage_pages` to extended permissions. In the authentication dialog i don't see the `manage_pages` permission and I still not see the fan pages in the response.

Comment: Did you acquire the permission `manage_pages` first?

Comment: I did, please look at the edited part of the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is :

```
FB.login(function(){}, {perms:'manage_pages'});
```